# Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync error in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, adb, enoent

I am new to react-native. I have created a demo project. Which was working fine . But now when i am doing react-native run android .It is building successful but giving me the error while installing.

```
Error
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 17.392 secs
Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools/platform-tools/adb -s ZY22432S6R reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools/platform-tools/adb ENOENT
Starting the app on ZY22432S6R (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools/platform-tools/adb -s ZY22432S6R shell am start -n com.music/com.music.MainActivity)...
```

In have even run the command `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.

But don't know that is the issue.
Any help will be highly appreciated.Waiting for your replies

Thanks

error screen shot

[image: error screen shot]